# Can't squash merge; <repo> was never added

Tags: git, git-subtree

I created a subtree link (child-repo) in another repo of mine (parent-repo). I added them using:

```
git remote -f <remote_name> <remote_url>
git subtree add --prefix <directory_name> <remote_name> master --squash
```

I was able to pull and push changes between the child and parent repos until I took a fresh clone of the parent repo. I added the remote in the newly cloned repo and tried to pull the changes from the child repo, but got the error: `can't squash merge; <directory_name> was never added.`
The subtree is no longer linked to its parent repo, however, the code is available in the parent repo.

I tried the git subtree merge technique to pull in changes using `git pull -s subtree <remote_name> master` but this isn't the subtree pull and also, I can't push changes using the similar push command.

Could someone please help me resolve this?